# java ee - authenticate users using servlets

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, jakarta-ee

I just started learning java, and have not worked with java ee. I need to authenticate users using servlets. Advise, please, sample code and technical literature. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. create a html form that accept username / password.
2. post these data to a servlet.
3. in doPost() read these data from `request` check them against database.
4. set some parameter in `session` that will show your system that this user is authenticated and logged in.

**Also See**

- [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security5.html)
- [A Simple step by step example + tutorial](http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/Full%20Login%20Example.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

[Very simple Servlet/JSP related code](http://simple.souther.us/) to get you started. And here is a fine example of [Form Based Authentication Using Servlet](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24253&seqNum=5).