# Authetication and Authorization in a Web Service

Tags: web-services, authentication, authorization

I am writing a web service in JAVA which will expose a product's API.
What i cannot figure out for my Low level design is, how to authenticate and authorize within my web service.

For example :- Who can or cannot invoke methods on my web service.
I want to build something like, one user can add an account however shouldn't be allowed to add user while some other user can do vice versa.

Can anyone give me a direction for best practices, i can figure out the details.

Comment: Please provide more details e.g. what type of API: REST? SOAP? Other? What framework?

Comment: Consider using a standards-based approach e.g. SAML or WS-Security or OpenID or OAuth for authentication and XACML for authorization. Check out vendors like Layer 7, Ping for authentcation and security and Axiomatics for authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a leightweight howto:

You could implement a usertable and provide a login mechanism. Every time a user logs in you could store the userid in a `session`. If an arbitrary request is received you check whether a session exists. If not you force the user to login otherwise you read the `userid` from the session. Then you can determine which functions the user is allowed to access.

Also this link about similar question on stackoverflow might help:

[Servlet user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733227/java-ee-authenticate-users-using-servlets)